# Missing "Google" in project properties

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse, google-eclipse-plugin

In my Eclipse App Engine project I have to set the "Use Google App Engine from time to time as it gets lost. But now suddenly, the "Google" menu in the project properties disappeared; instead I get a "Google App Engine" menu (not a submenu), where I cannot select the "Use Google App Engine" property, or the choose the App Engine SDK.

As the App Engine property is missing, I cannot use development mode, local Jetty doesn't show the application. How can I get the Google property menu back?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting all the settings files, I could pinpoint the issue. It was caused by the App Engine facet in the "Project Facets" properties. Don't know how that got activated, but after deactivating it, I got the normal properties again.